# schtasks.exe - how to make System as task creator?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

When using `schtasks.exe`, I can easily change "Run as" to be System (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`), with /RU option.

But I want to see task creator (under creator in Scheduled Tasks folder) to be System as well (now I see there my username).  How can i do it?
(If I use `AT.exe` the creator is automatically System...)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you could use `runas` to launch schtasks under the System account.

Comment: how can i do it? NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM has no password... and runas asks for password

Comment: @erez leave the password blank it will work fine.